# JAVA - Can't add Text Field and Button to container

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to do a little program that use some buttons and text field. 
I was able to create window with `JPanel` but don't have idea how to add button and text field

The code I'm using is:

```
public UI() {

    sprites = new HashMap();
   // spriteCache = stage.getSpriteCache();
    JFrame okno = new JFrame ("VoLTE Script");
    setBounds(0,0,SZEROKOSC,WYSOKOSC);
    JPanel panel = (JPanel)okno.getContentPane(); 
    panel.setLayout (null);
    panel.add(this);
    okno.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    okno.setVisible(true);
    JTextField pole = new JTextField(10);
    JButton przycisk = new JButton("teasda");
    przycisk.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 350));
    przycisk.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(przycisk);
    przycisk.setVisible(true);
    pole.setBounds (300,300,200,200); 
    pole.setLayout(null);
    pole.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(pole);

    okno.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
    });
    okno.setResizable(false);

    createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategia=getBufferStrategy();
    requestFocus();
   // addKeyListener(this);
   // addMouseListener(this);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the layout properly, when using border layout you need to tell it which border to use (, BorderLayout.NORTH or something), check out the tutorials at oracles page.

P.S. Think of how your naming your fields etc. Naming something "przycisk" just gives me a reason not to read the code further.

Comment: The P.S. is undeserved. Some users are more comfortable in their native language. Please respect that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code is from this site: [Example of Java GUI](http://java.about.com/od/creatinguserinterfaces/ss/Example-Java-Code-For-Building-A-Simple-Gui-Application.htm)

```
//Imports are listed in full to show what's being used
//could just import javax.swing.* and java.awt.* etc..
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GuiApp1 {

    //Note: Typically the main method will be in a
    //separate class. As this is a simple one class
    //example it's all in the one class.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GuiApp1();
    }

    public GuiApp1()
    {
        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();

        //make sure the program exits when the frame closes
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("Example GUI");
        guiFrame.setSize(300,250);

        //This will center the JFrame in the middle of the screen
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Options for the JComboBox 
        String[] fruitOptions = {"Apple", "Apricot", "Banana"
                ,"Cherry", "Date", "Kiwi", "Orange", "Pear", "Strawberry"};

        //Options for the JList
        String[] vegOptions = {"Asparagus", "Beans", "Broccoli", "Cabbage"
                , "Carrot", "Celery", "Cucumber", "Leek", "Mushroom"
                , "Pepper", "Radish", "Shallot", "Spinach", "Swede"
                , "Turnip"};

        //The first JPanel contains a JLabel and JCombobox
        final JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel comboLbl = new JLabel("Fruits:");
        JComboBox fruits = new JComboBox(fruitOptions);

        comboPanel.add(comboLbl);
        comboPanel.add(fruits);

        //Create the second JPanel. Add a JLabel and JList and
        //make use the JPanel is not visible.
        final JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        listPanel.setVisible(false);
        JLabel listLbl = new JLabel("Vegetables:");
        JList vegs = new JList(vegOptions);
        vegs.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);

        listPanel.add(listLbl);
        listPanel.add(vegs);

        JButton vegFruitBut = new JButton( "Fruit or Veg");

        //The ActionListener class is used to handle the
        //event that happens when the user clicks the button.
        //As there is not a lot that needs to happen we can 
        //define an anonymous inner class to make the code simpler.
        vegFruitBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
               //When the fruit of veg button is pressed
               //the setVisible value of the listPanel and
               //comboPanel is switched from true to 
               //value or vice versa.
               listPanel.setVisible(!listPanel.isVisible());
               comboPanel.setVisible(!comboPanel.isVisible());

            }
        });

        //The JFrame uses the BorderLayout layout manager.
        //Put the two JPanels and JButton in different areas.
        guiFrame.add(comboPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        guiFrame.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        guiFrame.add(vegFruitBut,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //make sure the JFrame is visible
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

For the future i will recommend you to use the **extends JFrame** so you can only write a gui like this without initialize a JFrame:

```
public class CalculatorGUI extends JFrame {
    public CalculatorGUI() {
        setTitle("Calculator");
        setBounds(300, 300, 220, 200);
    }}
```

I suggest you check out a couple of tutorials about how to create a Java Gui or sth.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for help and sorry for Polish names(fixed already).
I was able to add Text Area with scroll.
Looks like problem was in panel.add(this); putted before button and text field.
From my understanding if panel.add(this) is set before panel.add(pole); then panel.add(this) is set in front and pole is added but not seen.

Below my actual working code:

...
public UI() {

```
    sprites = new HashMap();
   // spriteCache = stage.getSpriteCache();
    JFrame okno = new JFrame ("VoLTE Script");
    setBounds(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    JPanel panel = (JPanel)okno.getContentPane(); 
    panel.setLayout (null);
    okno.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    okno.setVisible(true);
    JTextArea pole = new JTextArea();
    pole.setLayout(null);
    pole.setLineWrap(true);
    //pole.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    pole.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(pole);
    scroll.setBounds(25,250,500,300);

    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    panel.add(scroll);
    panel.add(this);

    okno.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

});
        okno.setResizable(false);

```
    createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategia=getBufferStrategy();
    requestFocus();
   // addKeyListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);

            }
...
```